# How to get PayPal Working properly?

Tags: java, rest, paypal

I am using java to integrate PayPal with my website, I have created a PayPal account in there have 2 SandBox Account
1.Business Account
2.Buyers Account
On My App and Credential Section, I have added an app and added a return URL there

I am using Check Out Button with the following code:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="paypal-button"></div>

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'production', // Or 'sandbox'

        client: {
            sandbox:    'clientId',
            production: 'LiveClientId'
        },

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        payment: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {

                // The payment is complete!
                // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
</body>
```

It allows me to enter credit card or debit card details, but once I enter my buyer's account funding Credit card details there It gives the following error

```
We're sorry, but your card issuer declined the payment. To complete your purchase, check your card details are correct or try a different card.
```

I tried it with creating another buyer account as well, there it gives the following error 
Sorry, but your card issuer declined this payment. To complete your purchase, try a different card.

Please let me know how to make it working properly.

Comment: how is this java/rest related? as far as I can see, all you show is a bit of angular front-end code

Comment: I am integrating it with Java and with Rest Api I am accepting the acknowledgements

Answer (score 0):

PayPal accepts MasterCard, Visa, and American Express. The card is requested to be used online in PayPal and support making online payments and international trade.